# Pentaho 8.2 : Pentaho never opens after increasing Java Memory

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I am using Pentaho 8.2 community edition.

I have the common error of Java Heap Memory.

According to this forum on other topics which refer this issue, I followed the instructions to increase the memory in the .bat file

But when I increase the memory (PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS) in the spoon.bat file, Pentaho Application never opens and no error message appears.

Do you know what i have to do ?

Thank You in advance, 
Thanos

Comment: Are you running a 32bit Java version? Those can't handle higher memory (or newer Pentaho versions, for that matter)

Comment: There is script to run in console mode. Start in console mode and read errors.

Comment: I have this kind of problem everytime I set it up on a new PC. I put a 'pause' at the bottom of the spoon.bat file, so I can copy the launch string, which I then run in a standard cmd prompt - so I can watch for errors, and change things manually to test what isn't working.